# Problem with Free space

Tags: filesystem, fsck

I was zeroing out the free space on my Ubuntu 12.04 using `sfill`, when the command stopped responding and I had to reboot the machine.

Now, the system says that it has no space left, and that it is running in low graphics mode.  Before this happened, I had nearly 500 gig free.

`df` says there are 0 bytes free.
`df -i` reports only 2% of INODES used.

I've run `fsck` and it didn't resolve the issue.

What can I do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sfill` is from secure-delete package (also provides `srm`)

Traditionally we zero out like this:

```
    cat /dev/zero > wtf; sync; sleep 3; sync; rm -f wtf
```

In your case, you were using `sfill`, not sure what arguments you used (what kind of files it was writing either), if you remember the cwd (current working directory) while your were running `sfill` from, you can `cd` there and use `ls -lahS` to see if there is huge files, if so, just delete it.

If you don't remember, try using the following command to find big files, the below example find 10GiB+ files.

```
    find / -depth -type f -size +10G -exec ls -lhS {} \;
```

NOTE: This has nothing to do with inodes (there must be a huge file which filled the HDD). `fsck` won't help because it is not a filesystem issue.

Comment: Thank you!  Please forgive my ignorance.  Although I've been using Linux for about two years, I'm still learning.  

It was a huge file, named oooooooo.ooo in the root.

Comment: No worries, Andrew.Good to hear you finally found the file. Just going back to the basics, I've made similar mistakes long long time ago. Looks like I've learned from mistakes.

BTW: I didn't expect sfill to use such a dummy name though lol;-)